# Where can I ask questions about proper object-oriented design?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I was in the middle of building an application, and I asked the following question about [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) best practices.

> [When Should I Use a Static Class and When Should I Just Use Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73991483/when-should-i-use-a-static-class-and-when-should-i-just-use-functions)

It was closed for being opinion-based. Where and how could I ask this question properly?

Comment: Maybe Software Engineering, see [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)